# can't implement readLine properly in java

Tags: java, readline

I have a text document that is read by a filereader method the text document looks like

```
1/2 0 1/6
6/11 1/6 2/10
```

The following code I need to read both lines of text

```
String line = br.readLine();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

    while(line.contains("  ")){
        line = line.replace("  ", " ");
    }
}
```

This is the main focus, If i print out "line" before the while loop it prints out 1/2 0 1/6 
However inside the while loop it prints out 6/11 1/6 2/10.

First of all, how come it doesn't print the first line, and secondly, how can i get it printing both lines?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `String line = br.readLine();` -> `String line = null;` will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `readLine()` twice before you process the line.

Just change the first line to `String line = null;`, that will fix this problem.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, was a little clueless, still getting my head around things, doesn't help my task is so confusing!! thank you again! Will accept in 10 mins :)